# Need help fixing this while statement

Tags: python

So I've been at this program for a couple hours now, its for a school project. I finally got near the end but there's one problem. The program is black jack and everything is going well except for when the user chooses to finally stand it still gives them another card / number before ending their turn. I decided to ask this question before taking a break and brainstorming on paper. If anyone can help fix this it would be very much appreciated.

```
    # Import the required modules
import random

# Print welcome message
print('Welcome To Blackjack!')

# State the rules for the game
print('This is blackjack. Rules are simple whoever has the biggest sum of the cards at the end wins. Unless someone gets 21 / blackjack or goes over 21 (bust). Bust is when a player goes over 21 and the lose. Once it is your turn you can choose to hit or stand, if you hit you get another card, if you stand it becomes the other persons turn. Your goal is to get the closest number to 21 without going over it. The game uses no suit cards. The values of the face cards are a Jack = 10, Queen = 10, King = 10, Ace = 11 or 1 whatever works the best. ')

# Global Variables
deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
dealer_cards = []
player_cards = []

print('Dealing...')

# Create the dealcard function to deal a card when needed
def dealcard(turn):
    card = random.choice(deck)
    turn.append(card)
    deck.remove(card) # Removes the card out of the deck so it cant repeat.

# Create the function to calculate the total cards that each player has
def totalvalue(turn):
    totalvalue = 0
    facecards = ['J', 'Q', 'K']
    for card in turn:
        if card in range(1, 11):
            totalvalue += card  # This adds the cards together
        elif card in facecards: # Checks if a card is a face card (J, Q, K,)
            totalvalue += 10    # This gives value to face cards
        else: # This checks if they get an ace and what works the best in case when they get an ace
            if totalvalue > 11: # If total is over 11 Ace counts as 1
                totalvalue += 1
            else:               # If total is under 11 Ace counts as 11
                totalvalue += 11
    return totalvalue

for dealing in range(2):
    dealcard(dealer_cards)
    dealcard(player_cards)

print(f"The dealer's cards are {dealer_cards} and the total amount is {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
print(f"Your cards are {player_cards} and your total amount is {totalvalue(player_cards)}")

# Take input from user
playerchoice = (input('Press 1 to start \n'))
print(f"You now have a total of {totalvalue(player_cards)} with these cards {player_cards}")
# Check what choice user chose and execute it
while playerchoice == '1':
    playerchoice = (input('Would you like to do \n1.Hit \nor \n2.Stand\n'))
    dealcard(player_cards)
    print(f"You now have a total of {totalvalue(player_cards)} with these cards {player_cards}")
    
      
# If they chose to stand move on to dealers / computers turn
print("What will the dealer do?...")
    
# Create game logic

if totalvalue(dealer_cards) >= 18:
    print(f"The dealer chose to stand their cards are {dealer_cards} with a total of {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
if totalvalue(dealer_cards) < 16:
    dealcard(dealer_cards)
    print(f"The dealer chose to hit their new cards are {dealer_cards} and their total is {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
if totalvalue(dealer_cards) == totalvalue(player_cards):
    print(f"Its a tie you both have {totalvalue(player_cards)}")
if totalvalue(dealer_cards) == 21:
    print(f"The dealer got blackjack! You lose...")
if totalvalue(player_cards) > 21:
    print(f"You busted Dealer wins... Dealer had {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
if totalvalue(dealer_cards) > 21:
    print(f"Dealer busted... You won and you had {totalvalue(player_cards)}")
if totalvalue(dealer_cards) > totalvalue(player_cards) < 21:
    if totalvalue(dealer_cards) < 21:
        print(f"Dealer wins they had a {totalvalue(dealer_cards)} and you had {totalvalue(player_cards)}")
if totalvalue(player_cards) > totalvalue(dealer_cards):
    if totalvalue(player_cards) < 21:
        print(f"You won, you had {totalvalue(player_cards)} and the dealer had {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
if totalvalue(dealer_cards) > 21:
    if totalvalue(player_cards) > 21:
        print(f"Both of you busted... no one wins its a tie")
```

This is mainly the part I need help on

```
# Take input from user
playerchoice = (input('Press 1 to start \n'))
print(f"You now have a total of {totalvalue(player_cards)} with these cards {player_cards}")
# Check what choice user chose and execute it
while playerchoice == '1':
    playerchoice = (input('Would you like to do \n1.Hit \nor \n2.Stand\n'))
    dealcard(player_cards)
    print(f"You now have a total of {totalvalue(player_cards)} with these cards {player_cards}")
```

Comment: The other 2 lines in your loop will get executed irrespective of the input, and then it checks if it's equal to `'1'`. You'll need to re-arrange that order or add an extra check to break the loop early when you get `'2'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a while true statement in a program that already has a while true statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70690667/how-to-make-a-while-true-statement-in-a-program-that-already-has-a-while-true-st)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dealing the next card even if they say stand. You should check the value of the input before dealing a card.

It's almost always simpler to use a `while True:` loop and break out when the end condition is met. That allows you to check the condition part-way through the loop body.

```
while True:
    print(f"You now have a total of {totalvalue(player_cards)} with these cards {player_cards}")
    playerchoice = (input('Would you like to do \n1.Hit \nor \n2.Stand\n'))
    if playerchoice == '2':
        break
    dealcard(player_cards)
```

Comment: Thank you, someone told me to switch from a while true to just while playerchoice == 1 but this worked thank you very much. You saved me from getting my marks drained and a lot of stress.