# How to make a while true statement in a program that already has a while true statement

Tags: python

I know the title is a little confusing but I want a way to ask the user if they want to play the game (blackjack) again. If they say 'y' the game restarts if they say 'n' it breaks. I tried adding a while true statement and it didn't work and I think its because I have a while true statement already in it.

Here's my code, if anyone has a way to ask if they want to play it would be very much appreciated

```
# Global Variables
deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
dealer_cards = []
player_cards = []

print('Dealing...')

# Create the dealcard function to deal a card when needed
def dealcard(turn):
    card = random.choice(deck)
    turn.append(card)
    deck.remove(card) # Removes the card out of the deck so it cant repeat.

# Create the function to calculate the total cards that each player has
def totalvalue(turn):
    totalvalue = 0
    facecards = ['J', 'Q', 'K']
    for card in turn:
        if card in range(1, 11):
            totalvalue += card  # This adds the cards together
        elif card in facecards: # Checks if a card is a face card (J, Q, K,)
            totalvalue += 10    # This gives value to face cards
        else: # This checks if they get an ace and what works the best in case when they get an ace
            if totalvalue > 11: # If total is over 11 Ace counts as 1
                totalvalue += 1
            else:               # If total is under 11 Ace counts as 11
                totalvalue += 11
    return totalvalue

for dealing in range(2):
    dealcard(dealer_cards)
    dealcard(player_cards)

print(f"The dealer's cards are {dealer_cards} and the total amount is {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
print(f"Your cards are {player_cards} and your total amount is {totalvalue(player_cards)}")

while True:
    print(f"You now have a total of {totalvalue(player_cards)} with these cards {player_cards}")
    playerchoice = (input('Would you like to do \n1.Hit \nor \n2.Stand\n'))
    if playerchoice == '2':
        break
    dealcard(player_cards)
    
      
# If they chose to stand move on to dealers / computers turn
print("What will the dealer do?...")
    
# Create game logic

if totalvalue(dealer_cards) >= 18:
    print(f"The dealer chose to stand their cards are {dealer_cards} with a total of {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
if totalvalue(dealer_cards) < 16:
    dealcard(dealer_cards)
    print(f"The dealer chose to hit their new cards are {dealer_cards} and their total is {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
if totalvalue(dealer_cards) == totalvalue(player_cards):
    print(f"Its a tie you both have {totalvalue(player_cards)}")
if totalvalue(dealer_cards) == 21:
    print(f"The dealer got blackjack! You lose...")
if totalvalue(player_cards) > 21:
    print(f"You busted Dealer wins... Dealer had {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
if totalvalue(dealer_cards) > 21:
    print(f"Dealer busted... You won and you had {totalvalue(player_cards)}")
if totalvalue(dealer_cards) > totalvalue(player_cards) < 21:
    if totalvalue(dealer_cards) < 21:
        print(f"Dealer wins they had a {totalvalue(dealer_cards)} and you had {totalvalue(player_cards)}")
if totalvalue(player_cards) > totalvalue(dealer_cards):
    if totalvalue(player_cards) < 21:
        print(f"You won, you had {totalvalue(player_cards)} and the dealer had {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
if totalvalue(dealer_cards) > 21:
    if totalvalue(player_cards) > 21:
        print(f"Both of you busted... no one wins its a tie")
# Print players and dealers card so user can see
print(f"Your cards were {player_cards} with a total of {totalvalue(player_cards)} \nthe dealers cards were {dealer_cards} and their total was {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")

# Ask User if they want to play again
```

Comment: Nested `while True` should work, but there is a better way: you can pack everything from `for dealing in..` to the end of the code in a function `play_a_round`. And in the end, ask if the player wants to play again, if yes call the same function (from within the function, that's fine)

Comment: One option is a second script that executes this script as a subprocess.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I am extremely new to coding is it possible if you can show me or elaborate on how to do this? Like how should I 'pack' and make the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code. I added the block that asks if the player wants to play again. I also added a stats() function that keeps track of the score. The stats function is not 100% functioning because of the the way the if statements are written. Sometimes the score overlaps, but I'm sure you can figure it out! You get the gist, though.

At the bottom I included a tiny sample code of asking the user whether to perform an action over and over. It's a nice template for future code if you need.

**** UPDATE ****
New Improvements:

1. Added a 1-second delay with "Dealing..." message
2. Added error handling across the board. Now when user inputs any value except what's expected, code raises an exception and won't break. For example, when user is prompted to enter either 1 or 2, any other input will raise the exception.

Issues:
Still having problem with scoreboard because of how conditional statements are implemented, but I'll leave that to you, buddy... ;)

```
import random
import time

deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
        2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
        2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
        2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
        'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q',
        'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A',
        'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']

dealer_cards = []
player_cards = []
player = 0
dealer = 0

def dealcard(turn):
    card = random.choice(deck)
    turn.append(card)
    deck.remove(card)

def totalvalue(turn):
    totalvalue = 0
    facecards = ['J', 'Q', 'K']
    for card in turn:
        if card in range(1, 11):
            totalvalue += card 
        elif card in facecards:
            totalvalue += 10 
        else:
            if totalvalue > 11: 
                totalvalue += 1
            else:               
                totalvalue += 11
    return totalvalue

#Added scorecard
def stats():
    print('________________________')
    print(f'Player\t\tDealer\n{player}\t\t{dealer}')
    print('------------------------')

def msg():
    print("Invalid entry. Try again.")


while True:
    try:
        options = int(input("[1] Play\n[2] Exit\nChoose action: "))
    except ValueError:
        msg()
    else:
        # if PLAY
        if options == 1:
            print('Dealing...')
            time.sleep(1)
            for dealing in range(2):
                dealcard(dealer_cards)
                dealcard(player_cards)
            while True:
                dealcard(player_cards)
                print(f"You now have a total of {totalvalue(player_cards)} with these cards {player_cards}")

                try:
                    playerchoice = int(input('\n[1] Hit\n[2] Stand\nWhat would you like to do? '))
                except ValueError:
                    msg()
                else:
                    if playerchoice == 1:
                        continue
                    else:
                        dealcard(dealer_cards)

                        if totalvalue(dealer_cards) >= 18:
                            print(f"The dealer chose to stand their cards are {dealer_cards} with a total of {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
                        if totalvalue(dealer_cards) < 16:
                            dealcard(dealer_cards)
                            print(f"The dealer chose to hit their new cards are {dealer_cards} and their total is {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
                        if totalvalue(dealer_cards) == totalvalue(player_cards):
                            print(f"Its a tie you both have {totalvalue(player_cards)}")
                        if totalvalue(dealer_cards) == 21:
                            print(f"The dealer got blackjack! You lose...")
                            dealer +=1
                        if totalvalue(player_cards) > 21:
                            print(f"You busted Dealer wins... Dealer had {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
                            dealer +=1
                        if totalvalue(dealer_cards) > 21:
                            print(f"Dealer busted... You won and you had {totalvalue(player_cards)}")
                            player +=1
                        if totalvalue(dealer_cards) > totalvalue(player_cards) < 21:
                            if totalvalue(dealer_cards) < 21:
                                print(f"Dealer wins they had a {totalvalue(dealer_cards)} and you had {totalvalue(player_cards)}")
                                dealer +=1
                        if totalvalue(player_cards) > totalvalue(dealer_cards):
                            if totalvalue(player_cards) < 21:
                                print(f"You won, you had {totalvalue(player_cards)} and the dealer had {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
                                player +=1
                        if totalvalue(dealer_cards) > 21:
                            if totalvalue(player_cards) > 21:
                                print(f"Both of you busted... no one wins its a tie")
                        stats()
                        break
        #if EXIT
        if options == 2:
            print("Thanks for playing.")
            break

        # This block asks player whether to play again
        # ***** BEGIN *****
        again = input("Play again? Y/N: ").capitalize().strip()
        if again == 'Y':
            # This resets deck
            dealer_cards = []
            player_cards = []
        elif again is not again.isalpha:
            msg()
        else:
            print("Thanks for playing.")
            break
        # **** END ****
```

Sample code:

```
print("Add two numbers")
while True:
    try:
        num1 = int(input("Enter first num: "))
        num2 = int(input("Enter second num:"))
        res = num1 + num2
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid entry. Try again.")
    else:
        print(f"{num1} + {num2} = {res}")

    another = input("Add other two numbers? Y/N: ").capitalize().strip()
    if another == 'Y':
        another = True
        continue
    else:
        print("Buh bye.")
        break
```

Comment: This code is so good!, its just super nice to play but there is in fact one problem when I run it, when in the beginning it gives you the option to play or exit, if you do play it gives you 3 cards?

Comment: Yep, 3 cards. I noticed it was returning 2 cards before, but I changed around. The only thing is the conditional statements that now need to be modified a bit because it interferes with the scorecard. That's an easy fix, though. If you think my code is helpful and answers your question, please mark it as "Answered" and vote up. Thanks!

Comment: Added some improvements. Check the code and comments.

Comment: Sorry for being late but yours was truly the right one, the scoreboard feature was so cool! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The `while` loop you created is only used for the card dealing part. But if you want to be able to loop the entire game again, you must create a second `while` loop which entirely contains the loop that you already created, and the entire "playing" part.
So you will need to shift everything by 1 indentation

Should look like this :

```
# define your functions and global variables

while True:

    while True:

        # Card dealing stuff
    
    # Game logic and display results
    # Wanna play again ?
```

Comment: When I do that, I have 2 problems. First problem is the cards not reseting after the game restarts and the other problem is in the beginning when it firsts asks you to 'hit' and you press it once it gives you two cards. This happens even if you 'stand'.

Comment: The first problem can be solved by moving the global variable definition part to the beginning of the first `while` loop so that it resets them at every new game.
The second problem however I am not sure. Are you sure that you indented everything correctly ? You should add exactly 1 indent to every line so that the relative positions of each line compared to the others remains "the same" as how it was before adding that `while` loop

Comment: I did that but that comes with another problem, the game doesn't load. I think its because the functions above it dont have the variables used in them in memory is the fix just moving them all the way below?

Comment: It should not be a problem that the variables used in the functions are not initialised, as they are not actually "called" when the functions are being defined.
Moving the functions inside the while loop would uselessly redefine them at each iteration, which is not needed, because the functions never change.
What kind of error message do you get, if you ever get one ? Could you also post your new code ? Maybe in a new answer

Comment: I managed to fix it it was a mistake on my part, I placed the global variables wrong.

Comment: I checked your pastebin link below, line 52 is mis-indented. There is another problem: even if the user wants to play again, it will never play again, because the last line is wrong. When you write `if input('Play again?: ') != 'y' or 'yes': break`, the `or` statement is an operator for boolean, so it will convert `'yes'` to a boolean, which convers to `True`. So it will always `break` whatever the user enters.

Comment: Instead, I recommend using `if input('Play again?: ') not in ['yes', 'y']: break`

Answer (score 0):

We can accomplish this, as you expected, using a while loop. First, I’d suggest moving the function declarations and other constants, like the deck, to the top. Basically, anything that won’t change between rounds. Then, put a `while True:` right before the game starts, so before you deal the cards. Use middle click to select the first space in every line and indent. At the end of the round, take player input by using `if input(‘Play again?: ‘).lower not in ‘y’, ‘yes’: break`

Comment: When I do that, I have 2 problems. First problem is the cards not reseting after the game restarts and the other problem is in the beginning when it firsts asks you to 'hit' and you press it once it gives you two cards. This happens even if you 'stand'. here's my code so far https://pastebin.com/pUcHVG8X

Comment: I also found a problem when typing yes to continuing it just closes the program. here's the code https://pastebin.com/pUcHVG8X

Comment: You need to define `dealer_cards` and `player_cards` inside the while loop to resolve the problem of the cards not resetting.

Comment: To fix the problem of always getting “hit”, I believe that is because you never redefined `playerchoice` at the beginning. Just have `playerchoice = 0` at the top of the game loop as well as redefining the player/dealer cards.

Comment: In regards to “yes” closing the program, you need to have `break` be on a new, indented line. Sorry if i forgot to include that in my original post.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but what do you mean by redefining the player/dealer cards and making the playerchoice = 0 does not help with it hitting even if you stand,

Comment: At the top of the game loop, have `player_cards = []`, `dealer_cards = []`, and `playerchoice = ‘0’` to reset the values.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code could help.

```
# Lumberjack
import random

# Global Variables
deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
        'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
dealer_cards = []
player_cards = []
play_again = True

print('Dealing...')


# Create the dealcard function to deal a card when needed
def dealcard(turn):
    card = random.choice(deck)
    turn.append(card)
    deck.remove(card)  # Removes the card out of the deck so it cant repeat.


# Create the function to calculate the total cards that each player has
def totalvalue(turn):
    totalvalue = 0
    facecards = ['J', 'Q', 'K']
    for card in turn:
        if card in range(1, 11):
            totalvalue += card  # This adds the cards together
        elif card in facecards:  # Checks if a card is a face card (J, Q, K,)
            totalvalue += 10  # This gives value to face cards
        else:  # This checks if they get an ace and what works the best in case when they get an ace
            if totalvalue > 11:  # If total is over 11 Ace counts as 1
                totalvalue += 1
            else:  # If total is under 11 Ace counts as 11
                totalvalue += 11
    return totalvalue


for dealing in range(2):
    dealcard(dealer_cards)
    dealcard(player_cards)

while play_again:
    deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
            10,
            'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
    dealer_cards = []
    player_cards = []
    play_again = True

    for dealing in range(2):
        dealcard(dealer_cards)
        dealcard(player_cards)

    print(f"The dealer's cards are {dealer_cards} and the total amount is {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
    print(f"Your cards are {player_cards} and your total amount is {totalvalue(player_cards)}")

    while True:
        print(f"You now have a total of {totalvalue(player_cards)} with these cards {player_cards}")
        playerchoice = (input('Would you like to do \n1.Hit \nor \n2.Stand\n'))
        if playerchoice == '2':
            break
        dealcard(player_cards)

    # If they chose to stand move on to dealers / computers turn
    print("What will the dealer do?...")

    # Create game logic

    if totalvalue(dealer_cards) >= 18:
        print(f"The dealer chose to stand their cards are {dealer_cards} with a total of {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
    if totalvalue(dealer_cards) < 16:
        dealcard(dealer_cards)
        print(f"The dealer chose to hit their new cards are {dealer_cards} and their total is {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
    if totalvalue(dealer_cards) == totalvalue(player_cards):
        print(f"Its a tie you both have {totalvalue(player_cards)}")
    if totalvalue(dealer_cards) == 21:
        print(f"The dealer got blackjack! You lose...")
    if totalvalue(player_cards) == 21:
        print(f"You got blackjack! You win...")
    if totalvalue(player_cards) > 21:
        print(f"You busted Dealer wins... Dealer had {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
    if totalvalue(dealer_cards) > 21:
        print(f"Dealer busted... You won and you had {totalvalue(player_cards)}")
    if totalvalue(dealer_cards) > totalvalue(player_cards) < 21:
        if totalvalue(dealer_cards) < 21:
            print(f"Dealer wins they had a {totalvalue(dealer_cards)} and you had {totalvalue(player_cards)}")
    if totalvalue(player_cards) > totalvalue(dealer_cards):
        if totalvalue(player_cards) < 21:
            print(f"You won, you had {totalvalue(player_cards)} and the dealer had {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
    if totalvalue(dealer_cards) > 21:
        if totalvalue(player_cards) > 21:
            print(f"Both of you busted... no one wins its a tie")
    # Print players and dealers card so user can see
    print(
        f"Your cards were {player_cards} with a total of {totalvalue(player_cards)} \nthe dealers cards were {dealer_cards} and their total was {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")

    # Ask User if they want to play again
    if input('Do you want to play again? \n1.Yes \nor \n2.No\n') == "1":
        play_again = True
    else:
        print("Thank you for playing Lumberjack with us")
        play_again = False
```

Here I just modified some game logic too. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: This does work and the logic is much better but the cards stay the same and do not reset if you play again, when I move the player/dealer card variables into the loop the game either does not start after it says dealing... or just has a infinite loop of your cards are [0] with a total of [0] and the dealers cards are [0] with a total of [0]. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @MythInSpace I've edited the code so that the deck and all the global variables are reinitialized at the beginning of the game.